# TD taking up entire width of row

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I need to set up an HTML table for an email in which each column has a set width.

The left column is just an image and the right is to have text. I have set td width but the td renders as 600px wide no matter what.

The email can be viewed [here](http://www.cs.unca.edu/~ruggiejl/fitzbroker.html)

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Fitzgerald Description">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>
        Fitzgerald Email
    </title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; background-color:#f8f6f2; font-family:Calibri, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetical, Arial, Geneva, clean, sans-serif;">
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px; max-width:600px; margin:0 auto 0 auto;" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="text-align:center;" width="600">
                <img align="none" alt="Fitzgerald Header" border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/MLEroOA.jpg" style="width: 600px;" width="600">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="244">
            <img align="none" alt="Fitzgerald Pictures" border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/nn93sj7.jpg" style="width:244px;" width="244">
            </td>
            <td width="356">
            <p style="font-size:18px; color:##71032d;">
                Going, Going ...
            </p>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="600">
                <div style="font-size:12px; color:#9d9d9c">
                288 Macon Ave. | Asheville, North Carolina 28804 | 828-251-1140 | <a href="thefitzgeraldatgrovepark.com" style="color:#9d9d9c; text-decoration: none">thefitzgeraldatgrovepark.com</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="600">
                <p style="font-size:12px; color:#9d9d9c; margin-left:18px; margin-right:18px;">
                Sales by Beverly-Hanks &amp; Associates, licensed in North Carolina. This is not an offer to sell to residents of any state or province in which legal requirements have not been fulfilled. This offer is void where prohibited by law. All features, services, amenities, descriptions and other information set forth in this communication are subject to change at any time without notice. The features, services, amenities and other privileges of owners of a Residence at The Fitzgerald are limited to those included in the Purchase Agreement and the Declaration of Condominium for The Fitzgerald Condominium. Certain mandatory dues, assessments, fees and charges apply to Residences at The Fitzgerald in connection with services, features and amenities described herein, contact a Fitzgerald sales professional for details. Depictions include amenities and furniture in the Model Homes which are not included in the sale of a Residence at The Fitzgerald.
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="600" height="10"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong, in my opinion. I would not mix tables and floats, they are two different methodologies. Before floats, all web design was done with tables, which means you don't need floats at all for table layouts. Really you should only use tables for presenting rows/cols data, but sometimes you might want tables as a rudimentary fallback method for email layouts. Though it seems most email apps handle floated divs fine these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `style="display:inline-block"` in this case and use `float:left` as Leo Abraham has stated.

Answer (score 3):

You have an uneven number of columns in each row. On `td` elements that you wish to span both columns, specify a `colspan` attribute of the number of columns to be spanned.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vBkdF/)

```
<td align="center" style="text-align:center;" width="600" colspan="2">
```

Edit:

Without this `colspan` attribute, each subsequent row's first column is assuming the width of the widest cell in the column - in this case the 600px wide first column of the first row.

Answer (score 1):

Add the style

```
float:left
```

to both TD and try. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WNeGk/)**

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why floating works in this instance? I thought td width was only supposed to be the width necessary to display the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this style to your table.

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

The default value is "auto" which I think is (weird) updated behavior, compared to the classic way of doing tables from 1994-2004.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

I'm still not sure why "auto" forces a "td" to take up an entire row, when then content is much smaller than the width of the table. Does the "auto" engine have some glitches or weird behavior? Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to state that td width has depreciated in HTML5. I recommend the use of css.

td { width:244px; }

Comment: most email clients use rendering engines that have been forgotten by time, so html5 is m00t. that's why most emails use tables for layouts, etc.

Comment: Very interesting. Also, I've never seen the word moot used like you did. Had to look that one up. Interesting definitions to say the least

Comment: I would have added this as a comment, rather than an answer.