# Float replacement for email in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

This is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436860/td-taking-up-entire-width-of-row).

I am writing this two-column email and I have been advised to use `float:left` on my td's so that the widths are appropriate for the email. However, I don't think float is supported in outlook and my right column is being pushed outside the bounds of the entire table.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svoYy.png) is a screenshot of how the email renders in outlook:

[image: Here]

Code can be found [here](http://www.cs.unca.edu/~ruggiejl/fitzbroker.html).

Comment: Please rewrite this:  "I have been advised to use float:left on my td's so that the widths are appropriate for the email."  <br>What is exactly the problem with the widths that **floating** could fix?

Comment: If you observe the other question you can see that floating both td fixed the width of the td's so that the left td did not take up the whole width of the email, pushing the right td past the bounds.

Comment: Ok. I see now; I updated my answer.

Comment: You should be using nested tables and only nested tables. While it takes longer to code, it is currently the only bullet-proof way of coding html emails. And with enough finger sweat, you can reproduce any layout with those, you just need to correctly cut your images and cleanly write your markup. (Nothing's worse than an email breaking because you forgot a row/colspan or to close a tr...

Answer (score 1):

Floating a `td` is a very strange thing to do. I haven't tried, but my guess is some versions of IE just won't do anything (therefore, for your concern, some versions of Outlook might show the same behaviour, or not, depending on the version and order of installation of MS Office and IE).

Floating any elements for email clients is a bad idea as well, since hotmail/outlook.com, and most versions of Outlook desktop do not support the `float` property.

See: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

EDIT: It has nothing to do with floating or aligning. You have 6 rows in that table, and the second one, has 2 columns, all the rest have 1 column. You have to have the same amount of columns per table, so you can use the `colspan` attribute on all 5 of the other `tr` in order for the table to account for the `tr` that has 2 `td`, like this `<tr colspan="2"...`. Then remove all floating, is unneccesary.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#adef-colspan for further info.

Comment: Yes I am aware it is bad practice to float a td however I have not found another way to fix the width of the first td with the images to not stretch to the full width of the table. I have tried setting td width, setting table layout to fixed, using align and none have worked.

Comment: adding a colspan might allow header and footer to cover the extra cells in the body, but you do not have full control of the cell widths. by defining a new table you are able to set whatever widths you like providing it's within the parent tables width constraints.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve a similar float effect using the align property, such as `align="left"` and nested tables.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="600">
<tr>
    <td align="center" height="100" width="600">
        header
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" height="50" width="298">
            <tr>
                <td>
                      column 1 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" height="50" width="298">
            <tr>
                <td>
                      column 1 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>

 <tr>
    <td align="center" height="100" width="600">
        footer
    </td>
</tr>
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2V2e/). i hope this helps.