# How to float in Outlook 2013?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, floating

I am trying to create a Responsive Newsletter for Outlook.
But one box doesnt want to work. I found out that floating and displaying doesn't work in Outlook 2013 from https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/.
On the left side in the box it has a picture (275x200) and on the right side a title, text and a button. The box has 4xtd with a width of 20px as a border.

I'll paste my code too, so you can take a look at it.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" >            
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            border:0;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #565656;
        }
        div, p, a, li, td {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
        }
        .span_buttonlink{
            display:block;
            width:100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow:hidden !important;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
        table.second_table table {
            font-family: Verdana,Arial;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #999999;
        }
        #floatleft{
            float:left;
            width:275px;
        }
        #floatright{
            float:right;
            width: 268px;
            padding-left: 3%;
        }
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 720px) {
        body{
            width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        img{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 2% 0 2% 0;
        }
        .first_table{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .second_table{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .second_table td{
            display: block;
            width: 90%;
            padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
        }
        table.textbutton_rechts td {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        table.second_table td table td {
            padding: 0;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
        }
        #mobile{
            display: block;
        }
        #floatleft{
            float:none !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        #floatright{
            float:none !important;
            width:100% !important;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
    }
    </style>    
<title>Responsive Newsletter-Template</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#e9eaed" style="background-color: #e9eaed;"> 
    <center>
        <table class="first_table" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <!--Start:Detailbereich-->
            <!--Start:1. Layout-->
            <tr>
                <!-- Spacer -->
                <td width="20"></td>
                <td width="560">
                    <table class="second_table" width="560" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Weisser Spacer -->
                            <td width="560" height="20" colspan="3"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-family:Verdana,Arial;font-size:12px;color:#999999;" valign="top" width="560" align="left">
                                <!-- Hier wird das Bild des 1. Layout im Detailbereich definiert und verlinkt -->
                                <div id="floatleft">
                                    <a href="http://www.newcomsolution.ch/" target="_blank">
                                        <img src="http://www.newcommunications.ch/projects/IPA_AKI_2015/Detailbereich_Layoutbild.jpg" alt="Layoutbild" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="floatright">
                                    <div style="font-family:Verdana,Arial;font-size:12px;color:#999999;margin-bottom:5px;font-weight:bold;">
                                        Titel Layout 1
                                    </div>
                                    <span>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
                                        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                                    </span>
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <!-- Start: Weiterführender Link 1 des Detailbereichs (Link von 1. Layout) -->
                                    <table class="textbutton_rechts" id="mobile" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 8px;font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.0; font-family: verdana; color:#ffffff;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#25A5DE">
                                                <span class="span_buttonlink">
                                                    <!-- Die Verlinkung und der Text im Button -->
                                                    <a href="http://www.newcomsolution.ch/" style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;">
                                                        Link-Button
                                                    </a>
                                                </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- Ende: Weiterführender Link 1 des Detailbereichs (Link von 1. Layout) -->
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Weisser Spacer -->
                            <td width="560" colspan="3" height="20"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <!-- Spacer -->
                <td width="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!-- Start: Spacer zwischen den Bereichen -->
              <td width="20" style="background-color:#e9eaed;"></td>
              <td width="560" style="background-color:#e9eaed;">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="20" style="background-color:#e9eaed;"></td>
              <!-- Ende: Spacer zwischen den Bereichen -->
            </tr>
            <!--Ende:1. Layout-->
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probable dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446504/float-replacement-for-email-in-outlook?rq=1

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't float text at all. You will need to set the text exactly where you want with tables pretty much. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(office.12).aspx are the standards that Outlook currently uses to render html mail. Drop "responsive" from the same sentence as Outlook and program like it's 1990...

Comment: i made it :D thanks for all answers